# Choice list field is not showing in getData function. how to get it?

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, symfony-2.5

I don't know what causing problem. I have a form with two field call name and category.

```
    ->add('name', 'text')
    ->add('category','choice', array(
         'choices' => $options['categories']
    ))
```

this categroy is a choice list. So here i have a problem, Once i submit this  form. I don't get any value of category

but when i change the datatype of category

```
->add('name', 'text')
->add('category','text')
```

then i can see the printed array of getData function.

Please help!!! where am i wrong?

FYI, Symfony version 2.5.4 and db engine is innodb with Fk on category.

**[EDIT 1]**
As i am submitting the form by ajax request and using rest api.

my function call for submitting the form is

```
$form->submit($parameters, 'PATCH' !== $method);
```

After submitting i can see only name not category in the printed object.

Comment: Are you getting no value at all or an integer?

Comment: It seems to me, that you are searching the entity field type (http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/entity.html)? But it's hard to say without more information.

Comment: I am getting no value. Actually i am using submit function to manually submit. I will updated the question